# WPF datagrid binding : add new item

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

I have the following window in my app:

[image]

The list is declared as : **IList < Vendor > _editList**;  and the datagrid is populated via : **dataGridVendors.ItemsSource = _editList;**

The "New" button creates a new Vendor and adds the vendor the _editList. **Vendor vendor = new Vendor();  _editList.Add(vendor);**

Unfortunately.... the new vendor does not show up in the datagrid........any ideas on how to make the new item show up ??

Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx):

```
IList<Vendor> _editList = new ObservableCollection<Vendor>();
```

The rest of your code should remain the same.